# PayPal online payments

Tags: paypal, integration

I am an individual, not a company. 
I need to start receiving payments online via PayPal.
Is that possible? Can I integrate paypal 'Buy Now' button? Will they ask details about my bussiness?

Thank you!

edit: What kind of membership do I need - standart,premier or business?

Comment: This is not a question about programming within the scope defined in the [help]. You should be able to get the information you need from [Paypal](http://www.paypel.com).

Comment: They dont give me an adequate answer.. :/

Comment: Perhaps not, but that's not a reason to ask off-topic questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be a business to use PayPal.  They will probably require your SSN at some point.  Creating a Buy Now button on your site is 100% allowed, and they won't ask you any questions other than your tax information.

Go to `Tools, PayPal Buttons, Create a Button` to make your first Buy it Now button.  Then take that source code and paste it in your site.